# Limit number of insert allowed per user

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

When a user logs in to my website, he goes to dashboard showing links. One of the link is `add course`, which take him to form where he can add courses...

I want to apply a limit of 3 courses insertion by all users, so that all user will enter 3 courses only. After that, a message should appear saying `limit reached`

Then he has to chose a plan. Let's say I have 3 plans: A, B, C

- A has limit of 10 courses
- B has limit of 25 courses
- C has limit of 50 courses

How can I do this?

Comment: Why was this modded down?, Is it a dupe? Least you can do is provide a link to the dupped question, so others can benefit from that knowledge. Modded it back to zero, because it looks like a valid newbie question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select the number of courses inserted by the user so far.

For this to work you will need the courses to have something unique to the currently logged in user, usually you use the id of the user.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS numCourses
FROM courses
WHERE user_id = insert_user_id_here
```

Would give you a result set with one column `numCourses`. Which will contain the number of courses your user has created so far.

Hope this helped.

Comment: @Enngr Ahmad: Don't forget to accept an answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way in which you can achieve this.

You can create a field like `selectedplan` for each user.

By default the value can be `default`. For plan A it can be `A` and so on.

> i want to apply limit of 3 courses
>   insertion by all users

When ever a user inserts a course check the `selectedplan` for that user and the number of  of courses inserted by the user.

Something like

```
if(selectedplan="default" && courses<=3)
   //add new course
else if(selectedplan="A" && courses<=10)
  //add new course
else
  // "Cannot add more course, limit reached"
```

When plan is changed update `selectedplan` field.